# Send String from C++ to C# processes using WndProc

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli, wndproc

I'm trying to send a String from C++/CLI to C#/WinForms

Here is my PostMessage

```
void Browser::NavigateTo(System::String^ address){
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle::Alloc(address, GCHandleType::Pinned);
    auto GCPin = gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    ::PostMessage(procWndHandle, WM_NAVTO, 0, (LPARAM &GCPin);
}
```

In the Winform Function, i'm trying to marshal it like this

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust"]
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
switch (m.Msg) {
    case WM_NAVTO:
        string s = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(m.LParam);
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm not getting an exception, however I'm not getting the address I sent, instead I'm getting Unicode Garbage.

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental, but I can't seem to see it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to clarify: The C++/CLI and the C# are completely separate processes?

Comment: Right, it is fundamental.  Only system messages can be automatically marshaled across process boundaries.  The OS has no idea what WM_NAVTO might mean and how its arguments need to be treated.  WM_COPY will work.  Do consider a named pipe as the far superior solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple issues with your current code:

1. [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) does not wait for the receiving application before returning. Therefore, the pinned object becomes unpinned before the message has been processed, and may be moved to a new location in memory. (This is probably not the major issue here.)
2. Assuming that your C++/CLI and C# components are completely separate processes, what you're doing is sending a pointer in one process space to another process. That pointer is no longer valid.

To fix #2, you need to copy the memory from one process to the other, somehow.

1. As Hans Passant said in the comments, you could use a named pipe to send whatever data you like to the other application. This is probably the best solution, and is definitely the most full-featured.
2. If you have to stick with windows messages, use the [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx) message. This message will have Windows copy your data (the string contents, in this case) from one process to the other. See the [Using Data Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009.aspx) example on MSDN.